Masking an Input to show "placeholder" text as user types - React
I need to create a phone number input with special input masking. The input will have a placeholder like this: (___) ___-____. As the user types, the "placeholder" text should slowly be replaced by the user's typing.
(12_) ___-____
(123) 4__-____
(123) 456-7___
My current code is broken in two ways (maybe more). It doesn't handle backspaces correctly and it doesn't move the user's cursor correctly.
My format function looks like this:
export const formatTelphoneNumber = (value: string): string => {
    const phoneNumber = getDigitsOnly(value)

    const areaCode = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3)
    const nextThree = phoneNumber.substring(3, 6)
    const lastFour = phoneNumber.substring(6, 10)

    const formattedAreaCode = `${areaCode}${"_".repeat(3 - areaCode.length)}`
    const formattedNextThree = `${nextThree}${"_".repeat(3 - nextThree.length)}`
    const formattedLastFour = `${lastFour}${"_".repeat(4 - lastFour.length)}`

    return `(${formattedAreaCode}) ${formattedNextThree}-${formattedLastFour}`
}

I have a code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/phone-number-masking-trqg64?file=%2Fsrc%2FPhoneNumberInput.tsx%3A6%2C1-18%2C2


My current code is broken in two ways (maybe more). It doesn't handle backspaces correctly and it doesn't move the user's cursor correctly.

It seems both of these problems are because you don't handle the cursor position.
You can use HTMLInputElement: setSelectionRange() method to change cursor position in formatTelphoneNumber method.
